# Unity on 14.10 - Desktop issue after dist upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade, desktop-background

I just upgraded the distribution from 13.04 to 14.04 and than to 14.10 in hope of some fixes but I got instead a big one that reminds me of very much of ...  windows lags. I hope is not a feature.

The Desktop somehow doesn't clear itself, the image bellow describes it better than words:

[image: Issue]

I hate to say it but it worked before just fine.

Did you experienced this issue ? Is it an effect fail ? Is it a 3D graphics fail ? And more specially how do I fix it?

Comment: 14.10 is not yet released, and is still being developed.  Questions related to the in-development release of Ubuntu are offtopic here.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't knew that.

Comment: For future reference, you can read [about what things are on topic here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) in the help center.

Comment: Ok, I will flag the question

Answer (score 2):

reset the unity

```
$ unity-reset
$ setsid unity
```

if that didnt workout try to re-install the unity & the desktop

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove unity 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d 
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo shutdown -r
```