# Desktop issue after dist upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade, 14.10, 15.04

I upgraded my 14.04 to 14.10 then to 15.04. 
after upgrade to 14.10 and reboot desktop acted strange and upgrading to 15.04 didn't fix it, see this image:

[image]

Filesystem and desktop icons are working but desktop background is blank and every window or pop up leaves an impression on desktop (remindes me of MS Windows!). Changing background has no effect.
I already tried first answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491018/unity-on-14-10-desktop-issue-after-dist-upgrade) question (reinstalling unity) 
Also tried removing nvidia-* and reinstalling xserver-xorg-video-nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the cause of this problem after a clean install.
I use nemo file manager and when nemo is set as desktop file handler this happens.
changing it back to nautilus solves it.